# How do I restore `tar.gz` among the archive creation list?

Tags: nautilus, 18.04, gui, tar, compression

Prior to Ubuntu 18.04, the compress dialog window listed a dozen file formats to choose from:

[image]

In the new version, the dialog window offers only 3 options:

[image]

This is somewhat limited in my opinion. I am used to compress my packages in the `tar.gz` format, and I like have all of them with the same extension.

I know one can manually open the *archive manager* window, drag-and-drop a directory into it and then create an archive to get a `tar.gz` package. Alternatively, I can use the terminal. But both of these approaches are somewhat sub-optimal and less immediate than the previous one.

**Q:** is there any way to restore the old compress dialog window in Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Nope, the new dialog window is part of nautilus itself, so short of modifying the code, you don't have many options.

Comment: @muru I think the question deserves a new answer and not being marked as a duplicate, as the comments under the linked question suggest that the solution is different for `18.04`.

Comment: And that's why I edited the answer.

Comment: @muru That was quick, I didn't see it. Then I accept the duplicate mark. Thank you very much